# Set classificationField property to read a list of fields

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, fields-attributes

I'm working in an ArcGIS Pro 2.8 Notebook. **GOAL:** How would I set the `classificationField` property to read a list of fields? I believe this is a python matter more so than arcpy. My whole script is meant to iterate 3 polygon layers in 8 maps and change the `breakCount` of the layers based off of each maps' corresponding `classificationField`. The polygons in each map are identical. I've been using [this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/graduatedcolorsrenderer-class.htm#C_GUID-797AEB2B-4613-4C08-BCC3-F1C0891AAE32) as a reference, which uses only one `classificationField`.

I've tried iterating the fields inside both the Maps' and Layers' `for` loops.

```py
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')

fields =  ['VaccPercentageTotPop', 'VaccPercentage0to18', 'VaccPercentage11to14', 'VaccPercentage12to18', 
           'VaccPercentage14to16', 'VaccPercentage16to18', 'VaccPercentage19to64', 'VaccPercentage65Plus']

for map in aprx.listMaps():
    print(f'--- map: {map.name} ---')
    layers = map.listLayers()
    
    for layer in layers:
        print(f'layer: {layer.name}')
        sym = layer.symbology 

        if hasattr(sym, 'renderer') and layer.name.startswith('BaseLayer'):
            #I'm working with graduated colors
            if sym.renderer.type == 'GraduatedColorsRenderer':
                Renderer = sym.renderer
                
                #for every map, change the symbology based on its corresponding field
                for f in fields:
                    print(f'field: {f}') 
                    Renderer.classificationField = f

                    classbreakvalues = [40, 45, 56.8, 100]
                    classbreaklabels = ['0-40%', '41-45%', '46-56.8%', '56.9-100%']
                    Renderer.breakCount = len(classbreakvalues)

                    i = 0 
                    for brk in Renderer.classBreaks:
                        brk.upperBound = classbreakvalues[i]
                        brk.label = classbreaklabels[i]
                        i+=1

                    layer.symbology = sym
                    aprx.save()
```

Unfortunately, it's changing all the `classificationFields` at once. So, the symbology field ends up being set for *VaccPercentage65Plus*, for example, because its the last field to be run.

```
--- map: Tot Pop ---
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Unified_09272021
field: VaccPercentageTotPop
field: VaccPercentage0to18
field: VaccPercentage11to14
field: VaccPercentage12to18
field: VaccPercentage14to16
field: VaccPercentage16to18
field: VaccPercentage19to64
field: VaccPercentage65Plus
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Secondary_09272021
field: VaccPercentageTotPop
field: VaccPercentage0to18
field: VaccPercentage11to14
field: VaccPercentage12to18
field: VaccPercentage14to16
field: VaccPercentage16to18
field: VaccPercentage19to64
field: VaccPercentage65Plus
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Elementary_09272021
field: VaccPercentageTotPop
field: VaccPercentage0to18
field: VaccPercentage11to14
field: VaccPercentage12to18
field: VaccPercentage14to16
field: VaccPercentage16to18
field: VaccPercentage19to64
field: VaccPercentage65Plus
--- map: 0-18 ---
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Unified_09272021
field: VaccPercentageTotPop
field: VaccPercentage0to18
...
```

Ideally: find the map --> find the layer --> change the property symbology. And maybe print something like this:

```
--- map: Tot Pop ---
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Elementary_09272021
field: VaccPercentageTotPop
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Secondary_09272021
field: VaccPercentageTotPop
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Unified_09272021
field: VaccPercentageTotPop
--- map: 0-18 ---
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Elementary_09272021
field: VaccPercentage0to18
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Secondary_09272021
field: VaccPercentage0to18
layer: BaseLayer_Processed_Unified_09272021
field: VaccPercentage0to18
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. There were quite a few things I had to do to get this to work the way I wanted. (1) Added a counter for each field in the list. (2) Added these lines: `sym.updateRenderer('SimpleRenderer')` & `sym.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer')` to get the symbols to "reset"  because they would not update as they were. (3) Removed this line: `if sym.renderer.type == 'GraduatedColorsRenderer':` because it was unnecessary. (4) Removed `for f in fields` because it was unnecessary. (5) Though not critical I removed `aprx.save()` because it slowed the script way down. Correction notes are also added to the updated script.

```py
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')

#make sure fields in list are in same order as maps in project
fields =  ['VaccPercentageTotPop', 'VaccPercentage11to14', 'VaccPercentage0to18', 'VaccPercentage12to18',  
           'VaccPercentage14to16', 'VaccPercentage16to18', 'VaccPercentage19to64', 'VaccPercentage65Plus']

c = 0 #### added counter
for map in aprx.listMaps():
    print(f'--- map: {map.name} ---')
    layers = map.listLayers()
    for layer in layers:
        print(f'layer: {layer.name}')
        sym = layer.symbology    
        sym.updateRenderer('SimpleRenderer') #### added 
        sym.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer') #### added

        if hasattr(sym, 'renderer') and layer.name.startswith('BaseLayer'):
            #if sym.renderer.type == 'GraduatedColorsRenderer':  Removed! 
            Renderer = sym.renderer
            #for f in fields: Removed! 
            Renderer.classificationField = fields[c] ### added counter

            classbreakvalues = [40, 45, 60, 100]
            classbreaklabels = ['0-40%', '41-45%', '46-60%', '60.4%-100%']
            Renderer.breakCount = len(classbreakvalues)

            i = 0 
            for brk in Renderer.classBreaks:
                brk.upperBound = classbreakvalues[i]
                brk.label = classbreaklabels[i]
                i+=1

                layer.symbology = sym
                #aprx.save() Removed! 
    c+=1 #### added counter
```

Answer (score 1):

**If I understood correctly**, your script doing what it supposed to do. Graduated Colours can be assigned to one specific field in a layer but you are cycling all fields and your symbology stuck at VaccPercentage65Plus provided it is the last element in your `fields` list. If you comment out `for f in fields:`, I think you will have the expected result. You do not need to loop the fields because the symbology field has been defined already.